# Google Maps Directions API duration_in_traffic different from maps.google.com

Tags: google-maps

Using the directions api (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) and providing a departure_time. This gives me as a result a  duration_in_traffic response.
However, the time I get in the response is way below what I see on maps.google.com for the same route and time request.

Is there a timezone conversion I should do? I'm providing the starting time using the javascript getTime() function for the requested departure time

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I was using getTime javascript function to send the departure_time to the API. But the Directions API is expecting the time in seconds, and getTime was giving it to me in milliseconds. So all I had to do was to divide it by 1000 and now Im getting reliable responses